# Changing number format using sprintf

Tags: php, formatting, printf

I have values like:

```
0.00000001
1.49000000
```

The main goal is to show 0.00000001 instead 1E8 on page.

This is code I have:

```
function correct_amount($amount) {
    $corrected=rtrim(sprintf('%.8F', $amount), '0');
    return $corrected;
}
```

This works perfectly but only in such cases:

```
1.92940000 -> 1.9294
1.04000000 -> 1.04
```

But with 'integers' I have below results:

```
1.00000000 -> 1.
15.00000000  -> 15.
```

How can I change the code to get the values without dot or with .00 ?

Comment: Tag your question with the proper language tag. Is this PHP?

Comment: yes, this is PHP. The tag has been added. Thank you Blender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a dot before the 0 in the arugument for rtrim.

```
function correct_amount($amount){
     $corrected = rtrim(sprintf('%.8F', $amount),'.0');
     return $corrected;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

brixenDK's answer is almost good. It has an error, because rtrim use all characters from pattern individually. 1000 will be 1.

brixenDK's corrected solution:

```
function correct_amount($amount){
     $corrected = rtrim(rtrim(sprintf('%.8F', $amount),'0'),'.');
     return $corrected;
}
```